# Azure Maps - Cluster Pie Chart Markers in Perspective View

Tags: azure-maps

I am trying to utilize the Azure Maps Cluster Pie Chart feature with on a map in a Perspective mode, and this does not appear to be possible.

Is there a way to implement this feature in Perspective mode?

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/HTML%20Markers/HtmlMarkerLayer/Clustered%20Pie%20Chart%20HTML%20Markers.html

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this. I hadn't noticed it didn't work in this scenario. I'm in the middle of a big update to this module and was planning to push it out in a couple of weeks. I'll investigate this issue and see if I can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug in the HtmlMarkerLayer class. It's actually being caused by a bug deeper within the SDK itself which I have reported to the team but will take some time to get resolved. In the mean time, here is a workaround you can implement to resolve the issue in your app:

1. Open the [HtmlMarkerLayer.ts file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/HTML%20Markers/HtmlMarkerLayer/HtmlMarkerLayer.ts) I'll refer to the line numbers in the file I just linked.
2. At [line 289](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/fb2d5c131d7ab1418a3331eb577071fdbdc51fcc/AzureMapsCodeSamples/HTML%20Markers/HtmlMarkerLayer/HtmlMarkerLayer.ts#L289) there is a line of code that looks like this:

`var shapes = this._map.layers.getRenderedShapes(null, this, this._options.filter);`

3. Replace this line with the following code:

```
const source = this.getSource();
const sourceId = (typeof source === 'string')? source : source.getId();

//@ts-ignore
const shapes = this._map.map.querySourceFeatures(sourceId, {
    sourceLayer: this.getOptions().sourceLayer,
    filter: opt.filter
});
```